# Tutorial Question dealing with interaction with ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

in [this tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/Using_roslaunch_Files_to_Spawn_Models) we see two packages being created by "you" one of them has a CMakeLists.txt and a package.xml as usual, and the other one, MYROBOT_gazebo has neither. Yet later, we see it being roslaunch 'ed like it is a package. Did the author just forget to include a package.xml in this package or is there something else going on?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6630/tutorial-question-dealing-with-interaction-with-ros/) by [4dahalibut](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/892/4dahalibut/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-07-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I've created an issue for this on the gazebo_tutorials repository. I'll be working on it there. Thanks for the report.

https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_tutorials/issue/9/tutorial-question-dealing-with-interaction

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2014-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2